# How find a specific row based on a cell value and insert current date into a cell of that row

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, find

I have a sheet that contains hundreds of rows.
The first column includes Reference Number which is unique to each row.
I want to find the row whose Reference Number is a specific number, for example 301, and insert a timestamp (date and time) into the cell of that row which is under column M.

I have the following code, which isn't complete yet and won't work.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var RefNumber = 301 //for example
var searchRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classes').getRange("A:A");
// get the values in an array
var values = searchRange.getValues();
// examine the values in the array
var i = []; 
   for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
    if(values[y] == RefNumber){
      i.push(y);
     }
     }
   // I have no idea how to continue the code! Please include your suggestions here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search a number from column A, and put the timestamp to the column M with the same row which found the searched number. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array.
- By using `getLastRow()`, the cost can be lower than that of "A:A".
- When `RefNumber` is found from `values`, it puts a1Notation to `i`. By this, the timestamp can be put using `getRangeList()`.

#### Modified script :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var RefNumber = 301 //for example
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classes'); // Modified
var searchRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()); // Modified
// get the values in an array
var values = searchRange.getValues();
// examine the values in the array
var i = [];
for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
  if(values[y][0] == RefNumber){
    i.push("M" + (y + 1)); // Modified
  }
}
// I have no idea how to continue the code! Please include your suggestions here.
sheet.getRangeList(i).setValue(new Date()); // Added
```

#### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output you want? I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Thank you very much. You got the point exactly as I meant. Your code works just fine. Bravo!

Comment: @Omid I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.